# issue with a android linear layout

Tags: android

i have a problem with the linear layout of android.

i have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/myimg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/a" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the problem is, that on some bigger devices everything is good. but on smaler devices i just see the image and the textview and edittext is not visible. and its not possible to scroll down.

how to avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried to use the ScrollView so it would stretch its size if needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the whole thing into a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). Nothing easier than that!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/myimg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/a" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because LinearLayout is not supposed to scroll down automatically. If you want to make your views scroll, you should place the layout inside a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/myimg"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```